# strip_tags is not allowing << and >> in php

Tags: php, mpdf

Hi i am trying to allow html tags in a string using strip_tags in php

But my string contains "<<" and ">>" and i am trying to allow those things using below code:

```
$allowTags = "<<>><span><s><strike><del><bdo><big><small><ins><cite><acronym><font><sup><sub><b><u><i><a><strong><em><code><samp><tt><kbd><var><q><table><thead><tfoot><tbody><tr><th><td><ol><ul><li><dl><dt><dd><form><input><select><textarea><option><div><p><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><pre><center><blockquote><address><hr><img><br><indexentry><indexinsert><bookmark><watermarktext><watermarkimage><tts><ttz><tta><column_break><columnbreak><newcolumn><newpage><page_break><pagebreak><formfeed><columns><toc><tocentry><tocpagebreak><pageheader><pagefooter><setpageheader><setpagefooter><sethtmlpageheader><sethtmlpagefooter><annotation><template><jpgraph><barcode><dottab><caption><textcircle><fieldset><legend><article><aside><figure><figcaption><footer><header><hgroup><nav><section><mark><details><summary><meter><progress><time>";

$test = "<span>white</span>red<<blue";
file_put_contents("test.log", print_r($test,true),FILE_APPEND);
$text = strip_tags($test, $allowTags);
file_put_contents("test.log", print_r($text,true),FILE_APPEND);
```

But its not working i am getting output as `<span>white</span>red` and expected output is `<span>white</span>red<<blue`

Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what the function does. [Read the manual when you want to understand what a function does](http://php.net/strip-tags). What you're looking for is [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), which encodes those characters properly for HTML rather than removing them.

Comment: Surely didn't 'strip tags' give you a clue as to what the function would do?

Comment: @Lee And since when is << a HTML tag? W3 must've updated the spec since the last time I checked. The function is just a little too greedy, but it's been that way for a while.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is not a tag, you have to use a regex (with `preg_replace()` for example) or `str_replace()` to escape it.

Comment: This really isn't even an answer. You loosely state the *what*, but have made no real attempt to explain the how. Aside from the fact that both `str_replace` and `preg_replace` are both a poor way to solve the problem, you don't even make an attempt to provide code that demonstrates how they would be used to solve the problem.